# async sqlalchemy 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a problem with async sqlalchemy. I am trying to create a record in my table in the database but it is not being created.

database connection

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

DATABASE_URL = "postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/asyncalchemystudy"

engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, pool_size=20, max_overflow=0)
Base = declarative_base()
async_session = sessionmaker(
    engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False, autocommit=False, autoflush=False
)


@asynccontextmanager
async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session


async def init_models():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        # await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
```

sqlalchemy model:

```
class users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    password = Column(TEXT)
    username = Column(TEXT)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Code for create user

```
async def create_user(session: AsyncSession, username: text, password: text) -> tasks | None:
    user = users(username=username, password=password)
    try:
        session.add(task)
        await session.commit() <- problem here
        await session.refresh(user)
        return task
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        await session.rollback()
```

After which the created user is used in the aiohttp session:

```
    async with get_session() as sql_session:
        task = await queries.create_user(sql_session, username, password)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
```

commit exception:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 761, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Python\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 519, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 68, in <module>
    asyncio.run(telegrator_parser())
  File "C:\Python\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 40, in telegrator_parser
    task = await queries.create_task(sql_session)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\sql\queries.py", line 23, in create_task
    raise ex
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\sql\queries.py", line 18, in create_task
    await session.commit()
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\session.py", line 578, in commit
    return await greenlet_spawn(self.sync_session.commit)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 134, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.throw(*sys.exc_info())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1431, in commit
    self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 829, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3363, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3502, in _flush
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3463, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 630, in execute
    util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 244, in save_obj
    _emit_insert_statements(
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 1237, in _emit_insert_statements
    result = connection._execute_20(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1620, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1487, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1851, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2036, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1808, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py", line 479, in execute
    self._adapt_connection.await_(
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 76, in await_only
    return current.driver.switch(awaitable)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 129, in greenlet_spawn
    value = await result
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py", line 408, in _prepare_and_execute
    await adapt_connection._start_transaction()
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py", line 716, in _start_transaction
    self._handle_exception(error)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py", line 684, in _handle_exception
    raise error
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py", line 714, in _start_transaction
    await self._transaction.start()
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\asyncpg\transaction.py", line 138, in start
    await self._connection.execute(query)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py", line 317, in execute
    return await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx", line 338, in query
  File "asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx", line 331, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol.query
  File "asyncpg\protocol\coreproto.pyx", line 1078, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.CoreProtocol._simple_query
  File "asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx", line 929, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol._write
  File "C:\Python\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 365, in write
    self._loop_writing(data=bytes(data))
  File "C:\Python\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 401, in _loop_writing
    self._write_fut = self._loop._proactor.send(self._sock, data)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is the result of an exception happening after another exception happened. When you are trying to commit the database transaction (in the line you highlighted), the event loop is already closed (due to the first exception), hence the error your are seeing from asyncio.

My suggestion to you is, run the application in debug mode and find where the original exception is being thrown and fix it.